# Tomcat serving wrong content

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, java

Any pointers would be helpful.

Text below is taken out of fiddler. This happens once in few days. Usually gets solved by restarting.

Thanks.

Request to a html page from SSL is returned with a png file.

```
GET https://www.@@@.com/account.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.@@@.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.@@@.com/account.html
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.215 Safari/534.10
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=@@@
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"4110-1287034824000"
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Oct 2010 05:40:24 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 4110
Date: Sat, 11 Dec 2010 15:22:40 GMT
```

SERVER.XML

```
<Connector compression ="on" executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443"/>
        <Connector compression ="on"  executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" address= ..
```

Answer (score 2):

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50957

Was probably the problem with 7.0.2 version only. Fixed after upgrading to current version.